# Ansible: How to set a port group for a vmkernel (vmk0) with VMware?

Tags: ansible, vmware

With the [community.vmware.vmware_vmkernel_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_vmkernel_info_module.html) module, I can get the data for `vmk0`:

```
{
  "host_vmks": {
    "changed": false,
    "host_vmk_info": {
      "esxi01.test": [
        {
          "device": "vmk0",
          "key": "key-vim.host.VirtualNic-vmk0",
          "portgroup": "Management Network",
          "ipv4_address": "10.0.0.100",
          "ipv4_subnet_mask": "255.255.255.0",
          "dhcp": false,
          "mac": "0c:68:37:e3:01:20",
          "mtu": 1500,
          "stack": "defaultTcpipStack",
          "enable_vsan": false,
          "enable_vmotion": false,
          "enable_management": true,
          "enable_ft": false
        },
        [...]
```

Please, how could I set a new portgroup to `vmk0`? Using [community.vmware.vmware_vmkernel](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_vmkernel_module.html) is crashing the ESXi.

Thanks in advance!